# Unable to insert data in MySQL from C++

Tags: c++, mysql

Am trying to insert data from C++ console application in mysql database table.

Am having table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Emp` (
  `empId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `empName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`empId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Now when I try to insert data, I get success message, but when I cross check it in the database, I am not getting any result.

Here's what I give the input to insert:

```
crazydeveloper@crazydeveloper:~/Desktop$ g++ InsertInMysql.cpp -o InsertInMysql -L /usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient -I /usr/include/mysql
crazydeveloper@crazydeveloper:~/Desktop$ ./InsertInMysql

Please Enter Your Name: 
Maddy
Connection Established Successfully.......
Connection Established Successfully.......
Your Name is Maddy
INSERT INTO Emp VALUES('Maddy')
Success....
```

**Update:**
When I insert 2 words for `empName`, only 1st word gets inserted:

here's the query

```
Please Enter Your Name: 
Brett Lee
Connection Established Successfully.......
Connection Established Successfully.......
Your Name is Brett
INSERT INTO Emp(empName) VALUES('Brett')
```

Here's my C++ source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <my_global.h>

#define SERVER "localhost"
#define USERNAME "root"
#define PASSWORD "root"
#define DATABASE "Test"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string empFirstName, query;
    int res;

    cout << "\nPlease Enter Your Name: " << endl;
    getline(cin, empFirstName);

    MYSQL *connect;
    connect = mysql_init(NULL);

    if (connect){
        cout << "Connection Established Successfully......." << endl;
    }

    connect = mysql_real_connect(connect, SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE, 0,NULL,0);

    if (connect){
        cout << "Connection Established Successfully......." << endl;
        cout << "Your Name is " << empFirstName << endl;
    }

    query = "INSERT INTO Emp VALUES('"+empFirstName+"')";

    cout << query << endl;

    if (mysql_query(connect, query.c_str())){
        cout << "Success.... \n" << endl;
    }   

    mysql_close (connect);

    return 0;   
}
```

---

**Bug Found**

Just found the error:
When I was not giving the column name `empName` in the query, the success message was printed. And now when I am giving the column name `empName`, the success message is not printed.

Query to insert:

```
// prints success message
query = "INSERT INTO Emp VALUES('"+empFirstName+"')";
```

Query to insert(after updating):

```
// does not prints success message
query = "INSERT INTO Emp(empName) VALUES('"+empFirstName+"')";
```

Kindly guide me where am I making mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table structure says it has a primary key `empId` as the first column.

So when you write query as

```
INSERT INTO Emp VALUES ('first name')
```

The value will refer to the column `empId` and the query will fail.

You will need to explicitly specify the column names in this situation , something as

```
INSERT INTO Emp (empName) VALUES ('first name')
```

Now mysql knows that the value is for the column empName.

Comment: Thanks bro.. you saved my day..
I have 1 more query, when I type 2 words separated by a whitespace, only the 1st word gets inserted, how to insert both the words ?

Comment: check the size of the column

Comment: the column is `empName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,` and if I give input as `AB CD`, only `AB` gets inserted..

Comment: hmm thats interesting can you print the query and paste it here I suppose that will tell more

Comment: check it now.. I have made some edits to the question

Comment: Hmm just checked and looks like while you add the name from the terminal its saves the first word to the variable `Your Name is Brett` `cin >> empFirstName;` and the query only gets the first part of the name for insertion since it reads one word at a time. You need to use `cin.read( empFirstName, sizeof(empFirstName) );` I am not so good in c++ but you need to use `read()` to get the entire string.

Comment: OR may be `getline(cin, empFirstName);`

Comment: You welcome and you almost took me to my college days while doing c++ and facing all these issues every day :)

Comment: Am not getting any success message now ? :(

Comment: You mean its not inserting and nothing is shown ? or just not showing `Your Name is some name` ?

Comment: Everything is working fine. Only Success message is not shown in the front end.. Am not getting this output: `cout << "Success.... \n" << endl;`

Comment: check here how to display the getLine() handled data in the I/O http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtUQBeUeI0o

Comment: Am not getting any success message in front end. I need that thing. and thanks for the video..